# Error when importing a 6.2 theme from its plugin sdk to themegenerator

Tags: themes, liferay-theme, liferay-7

I created a new folder test and navigated to the folder via command prompt.Ran Command yo liferay-theme:import.Then I get a question "What theme would you like to import".I give the path of theme in 6.2 plugins sdk.I get error meassage theme doesnot exist when clearly it exists in the path i give

Comment: I'm rarely working on the frontend, but it seems like "import" does not take care of upgrading, thus I'd expect a different operation to be required if you want to access a theme from a previous version.

Comment: Also, it would be strongly recommended to start the team from scratch. Too much changed to get a good result form just lift and shifting it to LFR 7

Comment: My issue was a space in the path.It resolved.I migrated the 6.2 theme to 7.But all the templates are written in Vm. I get a warning VM templates are deprecated in Liferay 7.May be because of that some contents are missing from the site now.. I understand that code migration have a lot of limits.But the client supports migration only.:-(